# Unable to retrieve session on the server side using next-auth in Next.js

Tags: session, next.js, jwt, session-cookies, next-auth

I'm currently facing an issue with retrieving the session on the server side while using next-auth in Next.js. On the client side, when I utilize the useSession hook, I can successfully obtain the session object. However, when I attempt to retrieve the session using getSession or getServerSession on the server side, I constantly receive undefined.

Next.js v13.4.6
NextAuth v4.22.1
React v18.2

```
export async function getServerSideProps({req, res}) {

  const session = await getSession(req);
  const serverSession = await getServerSession(request, response, authOptions);


  return {
    props: {
      session, 
      serverSession
    },
  };
}


export default function App({ Component, pageProps: {session, serverSession,...pageProps } })
{
  console.log(session); //undefined
  console.log(serverSession); //undefined
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

I have carefully followed the documentation provided by both Next.js and next-auth, but I am still unable to resolve this problem. Could anyone please help me understand why I am encountering this issue and provide guidance on how to retrieve the session correctly on the server side using next-auth in Next.js?

Answer (score 0):

this is `getSession` type

```
export declare function getSession(params?: GetSessionParams): Promise<Session | null>;
```

this is `GetSessionParams`:

```
export declare type GetSessionParams = CtxOrReq & {
    event?: "storage" | "timer" | "hidden" | string;
    triggerEvent?: boolean;
    broadcast?: boolean;
};
```

this is `CtxOrReq`

```
export interface CtxOrReq {
    req?: IncomingMessage;
    ctx?: {
        req: IncomingMessage;
    };
}
```

As you see `getSession` receives an object. so you should

```
const session = await getSession({ req:req })
```

Comment: I tried that too, but same result.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this problem.

The thing was that the .env file wasn't configured correctly. After I updated the URL, everything works fine.